# I want to untrack a folder but some useful files in the folder how do i do that on git

Tags: git, github

I do not want to be adding the files manually (it can be tedious and boring), i'm looking to untrack the entire folder excluding some useful files in the folder.

I've searched google for a solution but it seems this problem is peculiar.

Comment: Git never tracks folders, only files. Remove the files that you do not want to have tracked.

Comment: removing the files from the folder will lead to the webpage not being rendered properly because there are styling templates attached, it is important for the files to remain in the folder

Comment: Remove them from being tracked (`git rm --cached`), not from your file system

Comment: ok thanks, I just noticed when I try to create another branch it doesn't seem to work it keeps bringing  fatal: not a valid object name: 'master' error message how do I fix this please?

Comment: That's a different error unrelated to the question at hand. If you have a second question, please post a new one